# if any multiple condition python

Tags: python, if-statement, any

I have two lists:
list1 and list 2 with multiple strings

```
list1 = ('building1', 'building2')

list2 = ('07:00', '07:15', '07:30', '7:45', '8:00')

allbox[i].text = ('justastring with building1 and blah blah blah 8:00')
```

I need to test this condition: (how to proceed only when two conditions are met?) I thought the below is correct but it's not.

Currently, if one condition is met, doSomething() is executed. I want do execute doSomething() only when two conditions are met.

Does "if any" concerns two conditions?

```
if any (items in allbox[i].text for items in list1) 
   and (items1 in allbox[i].text for items1 in list2):
   doSomething()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: what is wrong with `if any(item in allbox[i].text for items in list1) and any(item in allbox[i].text for item in list2):`?

Comment: so you want `allbox[i].text` have at least one item in common with both lists. Right?

Comment: what is `i`? what exactly do you mean by 'only when two conditions'?

Comment: 'building1' and '8:00' must be included in the string to execute doSomething()

Comment: On a different note, those are tuples not lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `any` doesn't "belong to" the `if` - it's not special syntax, but a regular function:

```
>>> any([True, False])
True
>>> any([False, False])
False
```

It returns `True` if and only if at least one of the list elements can be considered "true".

Your second list will be non-empty, and a non-empty list is considered "true".

Since `any` is a function, you can also apply it to the second list:

```
if     any(items in allbox[i].text for items in list1) 
   and any(items1 in allbox[i].text for items1 in list2):
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you